# How to find the table names from a schema through Ado.net without using stored procedure etc?

Tags: excel, ado.net, schema

I am trying to read data from excel files using datatable.

The command "select * from [Sheet1$]" works fine but if the excel file has sheet with different name it gives error.

So now I need know how can I find the table names available in a schema using ADO.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Function will return the table name at the given position(eg, excel sheet) or return blank

```
Private Function GetTableName(ByVal ConnectionString As String, ByVal TableNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dtXlsSchema As DataTable
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    myConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    myConn.Open()
    dtXlsSchema = myConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, _
                      New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})


    If TableNumber > dtXlsSchema.Rows.Count Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return dtXlsSchema.Rows(TableNumber - 1).Item("Table_Name").ToString
    End If
End Function
```